# React JS - How to add a delay to text inside a component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React component with some text inside, but I want each line of text to render with a 2 second delay. However, I am having some trouble wrapping my head around the execution of the code. I am using React and JavaScript. I was thinking of using some kind of hook here but not sure if I have the right idea.. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React from "react";

function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
           <p>Render after 2 seconds</p><br />
           <p>Render after 4 seconds</p><br />
           <p>Render after 6 seconds</p><br />
           <p>Render after 8 seconds</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: You're on the right path. Have a search for `useInterval` or `useTimeout` hooks.

Comment: If you use `setTimeOut` and `setInterval` this should work. Here is an article I found helpful: [link](https://felixgerschau.com/react-hooks-settimeout)

Comment: @Nikimaria87 I'll defiantly take a look at this! Thank you so much.

Comment: Same to you @Andy, I'll look into it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) and [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) to do that. Here is an example:

```
function Home() {
  const [texts, setTexts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutIds = [];

    ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4"].forEach((text, i) => {
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        setTexts((prev) => [...prev, text]);
      }, 2000 * i);

      timeoutIds.push(timeoutId);
    });

    return () => {
      timeoutIds.forEach((id) => clearTimeout(id));
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {texts.map((text) => (
        <p key={text}>{text}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-ishizaka-ygyqmx?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Should the `timeoutIds` be part of the state? I have this doubt since a long time.

Comment: @NiceBooks No, you don't need your component to update when the the ids change, they are only necessary for the `useEffect` to clear the timeouts.

Comment: @Arkellys appreciate all the help! you da bomb!